# Show a map is a unital ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Define a map $\phi$ from the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$ of polynomials with real coefficients into the ring M of 3-3 matrices by:

$\phi(\sum a_{i}x^i)=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{0} & a_{1} & a_2\\ 
0 &a_0  & a_1\\ 
0 & 0 & a_0
\end{bmatrix}$

Show $\phi$ is a unital ring homomorphism.

Work:

Well to show its a ring homomorphism, I need to show:

$\phi(f+g)=\phi(f)\phi(g)$ and

$\phi(fg)=\phi(f)\phi(g)$

so:
for $f,g \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ where $f=\sum a_ix^i,g=\sum b_kx^k$

$\phi(f+g)=\phi(\sum a_ix^i+\sum b_kx^k)$=$\begin{bmatrix}
a_0+b_0 & a_1+b_1 &a_2+b_2 \\ 
 0&  a_0+b_0&a_1+b_1 \\ 
0 & 0 & a_0+b_0
\end{bmatrix}$=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{0} & a_{1} & a_2\\ 
0 &a_0  & a_1\\ 
0 & 0 & a_0
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}b_0 &b_1  & b_2\\  0& b_0 & b_1\\ 0&  0& b_0 \end{bmatrix}

=$\phi(\sum a_ix^i)+\phi(\sum b_kx^k)$ = $\phi(f)+\phi(g)$

Now for $\phi(fg)=\phi(f)\phi(g)$ I get stuck:

starting backwards:$\phi(f)\phi(g)=\phi(\sum a_ix^i)\phi(\sum b_kx^k)$=\begin{bmatrix}
b_0 &b_1  & b_2\\ 
 0& b_0 & b_1\\ 
 0&  0& b_0
\end{bmatrix}\times \begin{bmatrix}
a_0 &  a_1& a_2\\ 
 0&  a_0& a_1\\ 
 0&  0& a_0
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a_0b_0 & a_0b_1+a_1b_0 & a_0b_2+a_1b_1+a_2b_0\\ 
 0& a_0b_0 & a_0b_1+a_1b_0\\ 
 0& 0 &a_0b_0 
\end{bmatrix}

But how is this equal to $\phi(\sum a_ix^i\sum b_kx^k)=\phi(\sum \sum (a_ib_k)x^{i+k})$ ?

Thankyou.

edit: This question was answered very promptly.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying out $(a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^{2})(b_{0}+b_{1}x+b_{2}x^{2})$? What do you get? What happens to the higher order terms in two polynomials $f(x), g(x)$ in this multiplication?

Comment: $a_0b_0+(a_0b_1+a_1b_0)x+(a_0b_2+a_1b_1+a_2b_0)x^2$ Ignoring the higher order terms ($x^2,x^3$)

Comment: Indeed - do you see now how to deduce what you'd like?

Comment: ahh ok, I see the entries are the same....but why? I think im not seeing a key thing here...

Comment: Ahh of course, I see it. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, happy I could help! :)